# FIrebase jQuery .on method is updating array values one by one rather than all at once

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the values of the orders placed by users on the Corporate's page without a refresh. For this, I used the jQuery .on method. However, this returns the values in the array that I generated for the orders one by one rather than all at once. Is this just an issue with firebase or is it just my code.

Here is my code:

When I get the values:

```
 firebase.database().ref('Orders/' + user_id).on('value',  function(snapshot) {
     // Check if the user has any pending orders 
     if (snapshot.val() === null) {
         // No Pending Orders are Present
          $('.order_content-parent').html(' <div class="order_content">Hooray! You have no pending orders!</div>');

     } else {

         // One or more pending orders are present


          console.log(snapshot.val());


      snapshot.forEach(function(child){
           $('.order_content-parent').html(' <div class="order_content"></div>');

          var order = child.val().Order;

var key = child.key;
  console.log('Key is : '+key);
  getOrders(key);

});
```

When I insert the values into the database:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
     var myId = user.uid;
     const orders = ['Orders: '];
     $('.postData').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).html();
    orders.push(data);
    var database = firebase.database();
       database.ref('Orders/' + user_id + '/' + myId).set({
    Order: orders
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      // The write failed...
      alert(error);
    } else {
         $('.postData').html('Connecting...');

    }
  });
     database.ref('Orders/' + myId).set({
    Order: orders,
    For: user_id
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      // The write failed...
      alert(error);
    } else {
         $('.postData').html('Order Successfully Placed!');

    }
  });
  });
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Here is my console when I print the values from the database:

[image: This is my console. As you can see my code is running twice because the machine thinks it was updated twice, but it should only update once because I am inserting the data all at once]

Here is my database structure:

[image: This is my database structure, as you can see all the data is entered correctly at the same time]

Can anyone help

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is expected behaviour, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) states:

> The value event is called every time data is changed at the specified database reference, including changes to children.

Since your inserts are on a `each` loop, they get inserted one by one, triggering the `.on()` listener multiple times.

You could try inserting all the orders at once. Please try this approach and let me know if it works:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (!user) {
        console.log("No user is signed in");
        return;
    }
    var myId = user.uid;
    var orders = [];

    // Get the orders to insert first
    $('.postData').each(function () {
        var data = $(this).html();
        orders.push(data);
    });

    // Then, insert them all at once
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref('Orders/' + user_id + '/' + myId).set({
        Order: orders
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            // The write failed...
            alert(error);
            return;
        } 
        $('.postData').html('Connecting...');
        database.ref('Orders/' + myId).set({
            Order: orders,
            For: user_id
        }, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                // The write failed...
                alert(error);
                return;
            } 
            $('.postData').html('Order Successfully Placed!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked but may can you please explain the reason for the returns in the code

Comment: Sure, the `return` ceases code execution in the function up until that point. I use them here handling errors first to avoid the uses of some `else` clauses, making the code a little bit more "clean" and readable in my perspective. Of course, you can return to the `if` `else` if your prefer it that way. You can read a relevant article here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-clean-else-statements